# Combine FormRequest and CrawlSpider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to apply FormRequest [From here][1]:

```
#Request = FormRequest.from_response(
#         response,
#         formname='frmSearch',
#         formdata={'classtype': 'of'},
#         #callback=self.parse_links,
#         dont_filter=True,
#
#     )
```

For link in start_urls and to all pages that I get from the rules in my СrawlSpider.

```
class QuokaSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'quoka'
allowed_domains = ['www.quoka.de']
start_urls = ['http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen/']
curr_page = 0

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'.+'), restrict_xpaths = [u'//li[@class="arr-rgt active"]',]),
            follow=True, callback='parse_links'),
       )


def _url(self, url):
    return 'http://www.quoka.de' + url

def parse_links(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    lnks = hxs.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "img-lmtr") and contains(@class, "multi") or contains(@class, "single")]/@href').extract()

    filters = hxs.xpath(u'//div[@class="modal-title"]/text()').extract()
    for fil in filters:
        print "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+fil+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    for url in lnks:
        request = Request(self._url(url), callback=self.parse_object)
        yield request

def parse_object(self, response):
    item = AnbieterItem()
    hxs = Selector(response)
    item['Beschreibung'] = hxs.xpath(u'//div[@class="text"]/text()').extract()
    # item['Kleinanzeigen_App'] = '1'
    # item['Preis'] = '1'

    return item
```

If I try to use "start_request" to the filter, the spider does not use pages from the rules.

How can I solve this problem and apply this filter to start url and urls from rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to combine `CrawlSpider` Rules with `FormRequest` but I'd like to suggest that you replace the `CrawlSpider` with a generic `Spider` and create the `Requests` manually.

The `Rule` in your code does only take care of following the pagination (as far as i can see). To replace that you could use something like in the following code sample:

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'quoka'
    start_urls = ['http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen']

    def parse(self, response):

        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='frmSearch',
            formdata={'classtype': 'of'},
            callback=self.parse_filtered
        )
        print request.body
        yield request

    def parse_filtered(self,response):

        resultList = response.xpath('//div[@id="ResultListData"]/ul/li')
        for resultRow in resultList:
            xpath_Result_Details = './/div[@class="q-col n2"]/a'
            # Check if row has details
            if resultRow.xpath(xpath_Result_Details):
                result_Details = resultRow.xpath(xpath_Result_Details)
                # If YES extract details
                title = result_Details.xpath('./@title').extract()
                href = result_Details.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]
                # Code to request detail pages goes here ...
                print title, href

        # Use this instead of CrawlSpider to follow the pagination links
        xpath_NextPage = '//div[@class="rslt-pagination"]//li[@class="arr-rgt active"]/a'
        if response.xpath(xpath_NextPage):

            nextPage_href = response.xpath(xpath_NextPage + '/@href').extract()[0]
            nextPage_url = 'http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen' + nextPage_href
            nextPage_num = response.xpath(xpath_NextPage + '/@data-qng-page').extract()[0]

            # request = scrapy.Request(nextPage_url, callback=self.parse_filtered)

            # Create request with formdata ...
            request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formname='frmNaviSearch',
                formdata={'pageno': nextPage_num},
                callback=self.parse_filtered
            )

            yield request
```

Comment: Thanks, but filtered only the first page: "[scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen/kleinanzeigen/cat_27_2710_ct_0_page_2.html> (referer: http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen/)
############ Filters: Büros, Gewerbeflächen##########################

Comment: I've added some code to include the formdata in the pagination request. Please test if this works.